# How to exclude first sheet when code is run?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called "Start" where it contains all of the buttons (form controls) which parse data from a second sheet called "Data". The issue I'm having is this code writes to every single sheet and I'm not sure how to exclude only the "Start" sheet from it.

```
Sub CopyToAllSheet()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Sheets.FillAcrossSheets ws.Range("A:A").Columns(1)
End Sub
```

Please help, thanks!!!

Comment: Loop through all sheets. Examine the name of each. If the name <> "Start" take the action you want to take.

Answer (score 1):

Variatus is correct, you can perform a loop and check the sheet name against "Start" at each iteration. One possible solution is below. Please note that in order to avoid overwriting the "Data" sheet it too should be exempted.

```
Sub CopyToAllSheet()
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "Start" And ws.Name <> "Data" Then 'if name is not 'Start'
        ws.Range("A:A") = wsData.Range("A:A").Value
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!